# I want a template to return different classes

Tags: c++, openframeworks

long time reader,

I was wondering if anyone could help me make my code a bit simpler by using a template to return different classes derived from the same base. So I can call the functions on the classes instead of rewriting the function for each object call in a manager class. Here an example of one my current function calls:

```
void setLoopImage(AnimationManagerIndex & managerIndex, bool b)
{
    switch (managerIndex.animationClass)
    {
        case ANIMATION_CLASS_BASE:
        {
            vAnimationObjectBase[managerIndex.index].setLoopImage(b);
            break;
        }
        case ANIMATION_CLASS_MOVING:
        {
            vAnimationObjectMoving[managerIndex.index].setLoopImage(b);
            break;
        }
        case ANIMATION_CLASS_MOVING_BEZIER:
        {
            vAnimationObjectMovingBezier[managerIndex.index].setLoopImage(b);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a template function that returns these classes like so:

```
template<class T>
T & getAnimationObject(AnimationManagerIndex & managerIndex)
{
    switch (managerIndex.animationClass)
    {
        case ANIMATION_CLASS_BASE:
        {
            return vAnimationObjectBase[managerIndex.index];
        }
        case ANIMATION_CLASS_MOVING:
        {
            return vAnimationObjectMoving[managerIndex.index];
        }
        case ANIMATION_CLASS_MOVING_BEZIER:
        {
            return vAnimationObjectMovingBezier[managerIndex.index];
        }
    }
}
```

So the first function will become:

```
void setLoopImage(AnimationManagerIndex & managerIndex, bool b)
{
    getAnimationObject(managerIndex).setLoopImage(b);
}
```

Comment: You say all three are derived from the same base? Then you don't need templates. Just use `Base &` as return type.

Comment: What is the problem with your attempt? What is the actual *question* you have? As a long-time reader you should have had time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and if you haven't done that yet then please do so.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need templates for this. You can achieve this by making a base (abstract) class that has defines a (pure) virtual setLoopImage function.

```
class Base
{
    virtual setLoopImage(bool b) = 0;
};
```

Derive each of the following classes from the one above: vAnimationObjectBase, vAnimationObjectMoving and vAnimationObjectMovingBezier.

Then your getAnimationObject function would return Base&:

```
Base& getAnimationObject(AnimationManagerIndex & managerIndex)
{
    switch (managerIndex.animationClass)
    {
        case ANIMATION_CLASS_BASE:
        {
            return vAnimationObjectBase[managerIndex.index];
        }
        case ANIMATION_CLASS_MOVING:
        {
            return vAnimationObjectMoving[managerIndex.index];
        }
        case ANIMATION_CLASS_MOVING_BEZIER:
        {
            return vAnimationObjectMovingBezier[managerIndex.index];
        }
    }
}
```

Every derived class will implement the pure virtual setLoopImage function and you will call it on the derived class.

Comment: To improve the solution even more, have just *one* collection of objects, and the whole `switch` statement disappears, and all that's left is a single `return`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Agree.

Comment: Thanks answer, I'll implement it now. I'm intending to move all the classes different functionality into one class, but at the minute I'm writing them out separate to make sure everything works! How would I go about creating vector of different classes without having a vector of pointers of the base, which I've had bad experiences with.

Comment: Instantiate each class object and push_back it in a vector: new vAnimationObjectMovingBezier ...

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution to this problem is classical inheritance:

```
struct drawable_interface {
    virtual void setLoopImage(bool) = 0;
};

drawable_interface & getAnimationObject(AnimationManagerIndex & managerIndex) {
    /*Same code as before*/
}
```